# update route without reloading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a detail page for a given car id,
that page contains a list of photos (returned by the service)
and the user can click on those photos to see them.

I want to generate a URL so users can share the page with the selected
card, photos and the selected photo opened by default

Reloading the page is not necessary because I already have the car loaded
I just want to call the service to get the selected photo details only when the user click on the thumbnails.

I hope my explanation helps to understand the problem. this is my code

```
function CarsController($scope, $routeParams, $location, CarsFactory, PhotosFactory) {

    CarsFactory.get({id: $routeParams.id}).$promise.then(function(car) {
        console.log(car);
    });

    PhotosFactory.query({carId: car.id}).$promise.then(function(photos) {

        /*
            List all the photos with carId = car.id
            and the user can click to see a specific image ($scope.selectPhoto)
        */
    });

    $scope.selectPhoto = function(photoId) {

        /*
            clicking on any photo should update
            the URL to /cars/{car.id}/{photoId}
            I tried with $location.search('photoId', photoId); but it adds a querystring, not a URL segment change.
        */
    }

    if ($routeParams.photoId) {
        PhotosFactory.get({id: $routeParams.photoId}).$promise.then(function(photo) {
            console.log('Default photo: ' + photo);
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to generate the link in your page, and show it when the image is clicked:

```
<img ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv" src="..." />

<div ng-show="showDiv" >
    <a href="/url_part1/{value1}/url_part2/{value2}">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That will reload the controller and there´s no need to do that. that´s exactly what I want to avoid (the URL update is just to generate a permalink)

Answer (score 0):

To change a url path (or "segment") you can use `$location.path('/cars/'+car.id+'/'+photoId).replace()`.

With ngRoute handling the routing, Angular should intercept the location change and and prevent the page from reloading. The route parameters will line up with `"/cars/:carId/:photoId?"`, with the "?" making the final param optional. Thanks to the `.replace()`, the user won't have to click back through all the photos.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I want but it doesn´t work. It reloads the page (I see that because I´m seeing the xhr call in the network tab + text entered in the textfields in the page are missing) my route looks exactly the same as the one you posted "/cars/:carId/:photoId?"